Local Martingale with deterministic localization sequence is automatically true Martingale
Suppose one has a local martingale $(M_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)} $ with a localizing sequence of stopping times which is deterministic, i.e. in particular $(T_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} $ is simply an increasing sequence of real numbers towards $\infty$. Can one already conclude that $(M_t)$ must be a true Martingale ?
I assume so, since for any fixed $t \geq s \geq 0 $ the discrete process $(M_{t \wedge T_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is again a martingale and since
\begin{equation}
\{ M_{ t \wedge T_k } | k \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{ E[M_{T_k} | F_t ] | k \in \mathbb{N} \}
\end{equation}
it also is a UI martingale. Hence $M_{t \wedge T_k} \to M_{t} $ for $k \to \infty$ in $L^1$, hence $E[M_{t \wedge T_k} | F_s] \to E[M_t | F_s ] = M_s $ in $L^1$ and finally as $T_k \uparrow \infty$ one gets $E[M_t | F_s] = M_s $.
The context:
By Ito isometry/ construction, for $H: I \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ progressively measurable and $(B_t)$ a Brownian motion, $( \int_0^t H_s dB_s )_{t\geq 0 } $ is a martingale if $E[\int_0^\infty H_s^2 ds ] < \infty $. I want a quick way of seeing that this still holds true, if one relaxes the last condition to only $E[\int_0^t H_s^2 ds] < \infty, \forall t \geq 0 $.

Here's a a simpler proof: Let $0<s<t$. Pick $k$ such that $T_k>t$. Then
$$\mathbb E[M_t|\mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[M_{t\wedge T_k}|\mathcal F_s]=M_{s\wedge T_k}=M_s.$$

ah yes much quicker, thx.
